# How Do I Prevent Junk Account Creation?

Tags: users, spam, user-registration

I want to allow readers of my WordPress-driven sites who comment frequently the ability to sign up and have their own account on the site. However the ratio of actual readers versus spam scripts using the sign-up form is something like 1:100.

Is there a reasonable solution for preventing these bogus accounts from being created while still allowing reader sign-ups? Last I looked, I couldn't find anything for account creation like what spam-prevention measures are available for comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sabre](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sabre/) is great plugin, it allows me to block dozens of spam user registration per week.

It has also many useful features to control the style and captcha's complexity.

Comment: Installed and configured. We'll see how it goes, but this is exactly what I hoped to find. Thanks!

Comment: I'd never heard of this, looks awesome. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

I know of some sites using [TruBar](http://mnogo.truden.com/archives/148.html) successfully.

Is OpenID not also an option? I doubt the robots will know how to register for that?

Comment: Is there a WordPress plugin to graft OpenID onto WordPress?

Comment: Yes, there is:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/

Comment: However, this plugin doesn't appear to prohibit local user accounts, it merely augments the local accounts.